# How to automatically save a file received from server onto client

Tags: javascript, file-handling, fetch-api

In my web app users can see a list of some files on the server and they can they press a button to download one of them. This triggers a fetch api call to the server, which then responds by sending the requested file.

I've gotten it to work up to that point. When I check the response in the Network tab of the browser developer tools, I can see the picture that I sent there under the "Preview" section. I receive it using the fetch command below.

The next thing that I would like to happen is for the file to be automatically saved to the client's local hard drive (e.g. the Downloads folder). How can I do this?

```
            case 'GET_FILE':
                fetch(window.location.origin + '/api/get-file', {
                        method: "POST",
                        body: JSON.stringify(action.docData),
                        headers: {

                        },
                    })
                    .then( response => response.json() 
                    )
                    .then( file => {
                        console.log('API: got docTypes', docTypes)
                        next({
                            type: 'GET_FILE_SUCCEEDED',
                            file
                        })
                    })
                    .catch( error => {
                        console.log('API: docTypes get error!', error)
                        next({
                            type: 'GET_FILE_FAILED'
                        })
                    })
                break
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver

Comment: You can't, at least not without displaying the download dialog of the browser, or if the browser is set for automatic download it will save it in the configured folder